# Código empilhar e desempilhar uma pilha

Tags: c

Pessoal estou testando esse código no codeblocks e está dando um resultado muito esquisito, dizendo que a pilha está vazia e não consigo ver onde está o erro.

```
void empilha (int *p[], int *topo, int valor){
    if (*topo<10)
    {
        p[*topo] = valor;
        *topo++;
    }
    else
        printf ("Pilha cheia!");
}

int desempilha (int *p[], int *topo){
    if (*topo>0)
    {
        *topo--;
        return *p[*topo];
    }
    else
        printf("Pilha vazia!");
}


int main() {

    int pilha[10], topo=0;
    int i, valor=1020;
    for (i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        empilha(pilha, &topo, valor);
        valor = valor + i;
    }

    for (i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        printf("&d\n", desempilha(pilha, &topo));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O erro se encontra neste trecho:

```
void empilha (int *p[], int *topo, int valor) {
    if (*topo<10)
    {
        p[*topo] = valor;
        *topo++; // note essa declaração
    }
    else
        printf ("Pilha cheia!");
}
```

Quando você tem a expressão `*topo++`, você está, na verdade, incrementando o valor do ponteiro e *depois* aplicando o operador de desreferência `*` [(veja a precedência dos operadores)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). Desse modo, o *valor* de topo nunca é incrementado.

Para expressar, de fato, o que você quer, você deve usar `(*topo)++`. Assim, você desreferencia o ponteiro e depois incrementa o valor apontado por ele.

Note que o erro também ocorre na função desempilha:

```
int desempilha (int *p[], int *topo){
    if (*topo>0)
    {
        *topo--; // aqui, o ponteiro é decrementado antes da desreferência
        return *p[*topo];
    }
    else
    printf("Pilha vazia!");
}
```

Nesse caso, para decrementar o *valor* de topo, usa-se a expressão `(*topo)--`.

Há, ainda, outro erro no código postado. As funções `empilha(int *p[], int *topo, int valor)` e `desempilha(int *p[], int *topo)` pedem como primeiro parâmetro um ponteiro para uma array, o que poderia ser escrito como `int **p`.

Contudo, dentro do método `main`, você está passando como argumento para essas funções a variável `int pilha[]`, que é uma array, ou seja, um `int *`.

Você deve trocar os argumentos `int *p[]` por `int p[]` (ou `int *p`), além de alterar a expressão de retorno da função `desempilha` para `return p[*topo];` para que haja conformidade com a mudança anterior.

Por fim, note que o caractere de formatação da função `printf` abaixo deveria ser `%d`, não `&d`.

```
for (i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    printf("&d\n", desempilha(pilha, &topo)); // ao invés de &d, o correto é %d
}
```

Comment: Opa obrigado, mas aqui não deu certo, eu coloquei os parênteses em topo-- e topo++ e rodei o programa, deu um erro de Windows ("... Parou de funcionar - depurar ou fechar programa".

Comment: Note que as suas funções `empilha()` e `desempilha` esperam um parâmetro `int *p[]`, isto é, um _ponteiro para um vetor_, e você lhes está passando um vetor (e tratando-o como um vetor no corpo das funções). Tente dizer `(int p[], ...`

Comment: Além disso, também precisa dizer `return p[*topo];` no lugar de `return *p[*topo];` para evitar ler endereços aleatórios de memória

Comment: @Wtrmute adicionei as informações referentes a esse outro problema na resposta.

Comment: Troquei os argumento int *p[] para int p[] tirei os ponteiros antes do p e o resultado foi '&d' um embaixo do outro 10 vezes.

Comment: Talvez seja porque o correto seja %d e não &d.